# Error: razorpayInstance.open() is not a function - React and Razorpay Integration

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, razorpay

I am integrating Razorpay with my React application, and I'm encountering an issue with `razorpayInstance.open()`. The error message says "razorpayInstance.open() is not a function." I have followed the integration steps and used the Razorpay CDN.

explanation:
first i am getting the user's address once he hit submit button i'm calling my API end point and i can also get the order id  and passing it to my initpayment function which is responsible for razorpay checkout everything seems correct but why it says .open() is not function i include the CDN in index.html can anyone give me solution?
frontend code:

```
import React from 'react'
import "./shippingDetails.css"
import { Button, Divider, Form, Input, message } from 'antd'
import { useDispatch,useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { updateUserAddress } from '../../Features/signUpSignInFeature/SignUpSignIn'
import "../../projectStyling/RegisterPage.css"
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
// import   Razorpay from "react-razorpay"
// import Razorpay from "razorpay"
function ShippingDetails() {
 const dispatch= useDispatch();
// const navigate=useNavigate();

const currentUserInfo = useSelector((state)=> state.signInSignUp.user);

const initialValues = {
    Name: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.Name : "",
    Street: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.Street : "",
    City: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.City : "",
    State: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.State : "",
    ZipCode: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.ZipCode : "",
    Country: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.Country : "",
    Phone: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.Phone : "",
  };
  
console.log(currentUserInfo);
console.log(currentUserInfo.userAddress);
console.log('this is current user info and address from redux');
// this currentUserInfo has userId,name,email,wishList,shoppingCartList,userAddress,isUserActive..


const initPayment =(order)=>{

    console.log('i am in intipayment function');

    try {
        
        const options = {
                    key: process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_KEY_ID,
                    amount: order.amount,
                    currency: order.currency,
                    name: 'Gulzar Ahamed',
                    description: 'note: this is just a  Test Payment do not panic',
                    order_id: order.id,
                    // handler: handlePaymentSuccess,
                    handler: async(response)=>{

                        try {
                            
                            console.log(response);
                            console.log('this is the response after the order is created');
                            const verifyUrl="http://localhost:4000/verify";
                              const {data}=await axios.post(verifyUrl,response);

                              console.data(data);
                              console.log('i am in handler funtction after verify payment');

                        } 
                        catch (error) {

                            console.log(error);
                            console.log('i am in initPayment handler of error...');

                        }
                    },
                    prefill: {
                        // i think we need to use name,email,contact of user not me.
                    name: 'John Doe',
                    email: 'john.doe@example.com',
                    contact: '9876543210',
                    },
                    theme: {
                    color: '#F37254',
                    },
                    modal: {
                    // ondismiss: handlePaymentCancel,
                    },
            };

            const razorpayInstance = new window.Razorpay(options);
// below the error comes
                console.log(razorpayInstance);
                console.log('this is razorpay instance value');
                // this says open () is called with object that's not a razorinstance
                // let's ask in  stackoverflow
            razorpayInstance.open();

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('failed to create order this is an error');
    }
  

}

const handlePayment=async()=>{


     try {
        // if you want or needed you can also add orderAmount, username,userEmail etc and can pass it also...
         const response= await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/create-order",{orderAmount:1000})
        //   i think the response now will return the order value

        console.log(response.data);
        // now this returns  and contains order have properties like amount,currency, id,receipt,status,notes as array like that
        console.log('this is the create-order response data in handlePayment function...');

        await initPayment(response.data.order);

     } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        message.error( 'there was an error in handlePayment function');
     }
}

const onFinishFunction = async (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    console.log("value inside the shipping details");
    console.log(currentUserInfo);
    console.log('this is user information taken from redux');


    if (currentUserInfo.email !== undefined && currentUserInfo.email !== "") {
         
        try {
                const reduxResult = dispatch(updateUserAddress(value));
                console.log(reduxResult.payload);
                console.log('this is redux result in shipping details');

                const response=axios.post('http://localhost:4000/storeshippingaddress',{userId:currentUserInfo.userId,userAddress:reduxResult.payload})
                console.log(response);
                console.log('this is response from backend when storeshippingaddress api called');
                // navigate('/paymentDetails');


                // let's call the payment method of razorpay

                   handlePayment();// this is the function that will the payment route for order
            } 
            catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                message.error( <span className='custom-message'>{'error while getting user address'}</span> )
            }
               
    } else {
        message.error(<span className='custom-message'>{'Please sign in  to proceed further'}</span>);
        console.log('Email is empty or undefined. Navigation prevented.');
    }


};

    const onFinishFailedFunction =(error)=>{
           console.log(error);
            console.log( "error in shipping details");
            message.error(<span className='custom-message'>{'Please fill all the fields'}</span>);

    }

    return (
        <>
        <Divider></Divider>
            <div className='ShippingDetails'>
               
                  <div className='ShippingHeading'>
                     <h3 style={{color:"black"}}><b>SHIPPING ADDRESS</b></h3>
                  </div>

                  <div className='ShippingBody'>
              
                <Form
                                    initialValues={initialValues}
                                    onFinishFailed={onFinishFailedFunction}
                                    onFinish={onFinishFunction}
                                    labelCol={{ span: 2 }}
                                    wrapperCol={{ offset: 0 }}
                                >
                                    <Form.Item label="Name" name="Name" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                            <Input />
                                            {console.log(currentUserInfo.userAddress.Name)}
                                        </Form.Item>

                                        <Form.Item label="Street" name="Street" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                            <Input />
                                            {console.log(currentUserInfo.userAddress.Street)}
                                            {/* the above is working */}
                                        </Form.Item>

                                        <Form.Item label="City" name="City" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                            <Input />
                                            { console.log(currentUserInfo.userAddress.City) }
                                            {/* the above is working */}
                                        </Form.Item>

                                        <Form.Item  label="State" name="State" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                            <Input  />
                                        </Form.Item>

                                        <Form.Item label="Zip code" name="ZipCode" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                            <Input  />
                                        </Form.Item>

                                        <Form.Item label="Country" name="Country" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                            <Input  />
                                        </Form.Item>

                                        <Form.Item  label="Phone" name="Phone" rules={[{ required: true }, { max: 10, message: "Enter up to 10 numbers" }]}>
                                            <Input  />
                                        </Form.Item>

                                        <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 6 }}>
                                            <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary">
                                                Submit
                                            </Button>
                                        </Form.Item>
                            </Form>
                  </div>   
                
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default ShippingDetails
```

backend code:

```
const express= require("express");
const Router=express.Router();
const crypto=require("crypto");
const Razorpay = require("razorpay");
// require("cr")
// what are all missing 
//  need to create razor object or instance  and add crypto package is useful to make random string for reciept no. in options property

Router.post('/create-order', async (req, res) => {
   

    const {orderAmount}= req.body;
    console.log(orderAmount);
    console.log('this is order amount taken rom frontend data');
  const options = {
      // get the amount dynamically from req.body and multiply by 100 razor pay accepts paise format
      amount: orderAmount * 100, // amount in paise (e.g., 1000 paise = ₹10)
      currency: 'INR',
      // receipt: 'order_receipt',
      receipt:crypto.randomBytes(10).toString("hex"),
      payment_capture: 1,
     };

    try {
// first create razor pay object or instance
        const razorPay = new Razorpay(
            {
              key_id:process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_KEY_ID,
              key_secret:process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_SECRET_KEY 
              // please check the above is available or not
      // console.log(key_id);
            } 
        )
// the create function take s (options,(error,response)=>{if(error)conslow.log(error); reutrn status as 500})
      // const order =
       await razorPay.orders.create(options,(error,order)=>{
       console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_KEY_ID) ;
       console.log('this is key value'); 
       console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_SECRET_KEY) ;
  console.log('this s secret key');
        if(error)
              {
                return res.status(500).json({message:'there is an error while getting order from api'});
             }

            return res.status(200).json({message:"receive order from backend",order:order});
       });
      // send order in response as 200 with order payload
      // res.json(order);
    }
     catch (error) {
      // actually this is executing don't know why it is like that..
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to create order' });
    }
  });


  Router.post("/verify",async(req,res)=>{

            try {
              
               const {razorpay_order_id,razorpay_payment_id,razorpay_signature}= req.body;

               const sign=razorpay_order_id +"|" +razorpay_payment_id;

                const exprectedSign= crypto.createHmac("sha256",process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_SECRET_KEY)
                .update(sign.toString())
                .digest("hex");

                if(razorpay_signature===exprectedSign){
                  // then its a valid signature
                  return res.status(200).json({message:"paymemt verified successfully"});
                }else{
                    return res.status(400).json({message:"invalid signature send!"});
                }

            } catch (error) {

                console.log(error);
                res.status(500).json( { message: 'internal server error'} )
            }
       }
  )

  module.exports=Router;
```

Comment: Have you added the razorpay checkout script to the index file?

Comment: <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/razorpay.js"></script>
@KabileeshG this is the one i added  in head tag of my index.html

Comment: can you tell me a reason why the checkout is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the `script` has loaded completely. External scripts may take time to load, So handle with `Promise`.

```
const loadScript = (src) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = src;
    script.onload = () => {
      resolve(true);
    };
    script.onerror = () => {
      resolve(false);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  });
};

const initPayment = async (order)=>{
    const res = await loadScript("https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js");

     if (!res) {
        alert("Razropay failed to load!!");
        return;
     }
   
    try {
        
        const options = {
            // Your options
            key: process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_KEY_ID,
            amount: order.amount,
            currency: order.currency,
            name: 'Gulzar Ahamed',
            description: 'note: this is just a  Test Payment do not panic',
            order_id: order.id,
            callback_url: "http://localhost:4000/verify",
            handler: async(response)=>{
                         console.log(response);
                         console.log('this is the response after the order is created');
                         console.log('i am in handler funtction after verify payment');
                     },
             prefill: {
                    name: 'John Doe',
                    email: 'john.doe@example.com',
                    contact: '9876543210',
                    },
                    theme: {
                    color: '#F37254',
                    },
                    modal: {
                    // ondismiss: handlePaymentCancel,
                    },
        };

        const razorpayInstance = new window.Razorpay(options);
       
        console.log(razorpayInstance);
        console.log('this is razorpay instance value');
        
        // You can handle payment failure by listening to the failure event.
        razorpayInstance.on("payment.failed", async (response) => {
               console.log(response.error.description);
        });

        razorpayInstance.open();

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('failed to create order this is an error');
    }
}
```

This ensures that `Razorpay` instance is initialized only after the `script` has been loaded.

Use `callback_url` to verify signature, to which the `razorpay` server will send the `response`. And then handle the `success response` through `handler` function.

Comment: hi thanks a lot i can see checkout UI but why i'm unable to may any test payment i used all the options but  shows error like this Payment failed
We are facing some trouble completing your request at the moment.

Comment: please provide the correct of it

Comment: You need to mention the `callback-url` to which the `response` from the razorpay server will be sent, then which you can verify the `razorpay-signature` and the response from your backend will be handled by the `handler` function.

Comment: You need not to hit the `"/verify"` end-point in handler function. I will be hit by the rayzorpay server. 
I have updated the solution to solve the mentioned problem. I hope this works fine.

Comment: i don't understand ,could you provide the comprehensive details  about this i have used handler property there i handled one function this will take response which razorpay id,signiture etc..contains  i am unable in my code i have console.log(response) in handler property in  options but  i am unable to see even it's not calling that function

Comment: code
: 
"SERVER_ERROR"
description
: 
"We are facing some trouble completing your request at the moment. Please try again shortly."
metadata
: 
{}
reason
: 
"NA"
source
: 
"NA"
step
: 
"NA" i get this message in razorpayInstance.on()

Answer (score 0):

```
  import React from 'react'
        import "./shippingDetails.css"
        import { Button, Divider, Form, Input, message } from 'antd'
        import { useDispatch,useSelector } from 'react-redux'
        import { updateUserAddress } from '../../Features/signUpSignInFeature/SignUpSignIn'
        import "../../projectStyling/RegisterPage.css"
        // import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
        import axios from 'axios'
        
    
    function ShippingDetails() {
     const dispatch= useDispatch();
    // const navigate=useNavigate();
    
    const currentUserInfo = useSelector((state)=> state.signInSignUp.user);
    
    const initialValues = {
        Name: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.Name : "",
        Street: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.Street : "",
        City: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.City : "",
        State: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.State : "",
        ZipCode: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.ZipCode : "",
        Country: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.Country : "",
        Phone: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.Phone : "",
      };
      
    console.log(currentUserInfo);
    console.log(currentUserInfo.userAddress);
    console.log('this is current user info and address from redux');
    // this currentUserInfo has userId,name,email,wishList,shoppingCartList,userAddress,isUserActive..
    
    
    const loadScript = (src) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          const script = document.createElement("script");
          script.src = src;
          script.onload = () => {
            resolve(true);
          };
          script.onerror = () => {
            resolve(false);
          };
          document.body.appendChild(script);
        });
      };
    
    const initPayment =async(order)=>{
    
        console.log('i am in intipayment function');
    
        try {
            
            const res = await loadScript("https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js");
        
            console.log(res);
            console.log('this is res from the razorpay server that im callling expecitly');
                if (!res) {
                   alert("Razropay failed to load!!");
                   return;
                }
    
            const options = {
                        key: process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_KEY_ID,
                        amount: order.amount,
                        currency: order.currency,
                        name: 'Gulzar Ahamed',
                        description: 'note: this is just a  Test Payment do not panic',
                        order_id: order.id,
     
                        // handler: handlePaymentSuccess, 
                        // mention the callback-url to which the response from the razorpay server will be sent,
                        handler: async(response)=>{
    
                            try {
                                console.log('i am here in handler function..');
                                console.log(response);
                                console.log('this is the response after the order is created');
                                const verifyUrl="http://localhost:4000/verify";
                                  const {data}=await axios.post(verifyUrl,response);
                                  console.data(data);
                                  console.log('i am in handler funtction after verify payment');
                            } 
                            catch (error) {
                              console.log(error);
                                console.log('i am in initPayment handler of error...');
                            }
                        },
                        prefill: {
                            // i think we need to use name,email,contact of user not me.
                        name: 'John Doe',
                        email: 'john.doe@example.com',
                        contact: '9876543210',
                        },
                        theme: {
                        color: '#F37254',
                        },
                        // modal: {
                        // // ondismiss: handlePaymentCancel,
                        // },
                };
                // const razorpayInstance = new window.Razorpay(options);
                const razorpayInstance =new window.Razorpay(options);
    // below the error comes
                    console.log(razorpayInstance);
                    console.log('this is razorpay instance value');
                    // this says open () is called with object that's not a razorinstance
                    // let's ask in  stackoverflow
                    razorpayInstance.on("payment.failed", async (response) => {
                        console.log(response);
                        console.log('this is response object in payment failed instance'); 
                        console.log(response.error.description);
                        console.log('this the response.error.description in on event');
                 });
                razorpayInstance.open();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log('failed to create order this is an error');
        }
    }
    
    const handlePayment=async()=>{
    
    
         try {
            // if you want or needed you can also add orderAmount, username,userEmail etc and can pass it also...
             const response= await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/create-order",{orderAmount:1000})
            //   i think the response now will return the order value
    
            console.log(response.data);
            // now this returns  and contains order have properties like amount,currency, id,receipt,status,notes as array like that
            console.log('this is the create-order response data in handlePayment function...');
    
            await initPayment(response.data.order);
    
         } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            message.error( 'there was an error in handlePayment function');
         }
    }
    
    const onFinishFunction = async (value) => {
        console.log(value);
        console.log("value inside the shipping details");
        console.log(currentUserInfo);
        console.log('this is user information taken from redux');
    
    
        if (currentUserInfo.email !== undefined && currentUserInfo.email !== "") {
             
            try {
                    const reduxResult = dispatch(updateUserAddress(value));
                    console.log(reduxResult.payload);
                    console.log('this is redux result in shipping details');
    
                    const response=axios.post('http://localhost:4000/storeshippingaddress',{userId:currentUserInfo.userId,userAddress:reduxResult.payload})
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log('this is response from backend when storeshippingaddress api called');
                    // navigate('/paymentDetails');
    
    
                    // let's call the payment method of razorpay
    
                       handlePayment();// this is the function that will the payment route for order
                } 
                catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    message.error( <span className='custom-message'>{'error while getting user address'}</span> )
                }
                   
        } else {
            message.error(<span className='custom-message'>{'Please sign in  to proceed further'}</span>);
            console.log('Email is empty or undefined. Navigation prevented.');
        }
    
    
    };
    
        const onFinishFailedFunction =(error)=>{
               console.log(error);
                console.log( "error in shipping details");
                message.error(<span className='custom-message'>{'Please fill all the fields'}</span>);
    
        }
    
        return (
            <>
            <Divider></Divider>
                <div className='ShippingDetails'>
                   
                      <div className='ShippingHeading'>
                         <h3 style={{color:"black"}}><b>SHIPPING ADDRESS</b></h3>
                      </div>
    
                      <div className='ShippingBody'>
                  
                    <Form
                                        initialValues={initialValues}
                                        onFinishFailed={onFinishFailedFunction}
                                        onFinish={onFinishFunction}
                                        labelCol={{ span: 2 }}
                                        wrapperCol={{ offset: 0 }}
                                    >
                                        <Form.Item label="Name" name="Name" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                                <Input />
                                                {console.log(currentUserInfo.userAddress.Name)}
                                            </Form.Item>
    
                                            <Form.Item label="Street" name="Street" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                                <Input />
                                                {console.log(currentUserInfo.userAddress.Street)}
                                                {/* the above is working */}
                                            </Form.Item>
    
                                            <Form.Item label="City" name="City" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                                <Input />
                                                { console.log(currentUserInfo.userAddress.City) }
                                                {/* the above is working */}
                                            </Form.Item>
    
                                            <Form.Item  label="State" name="State" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                                <Input  />
                                            </Form.Item>
    
                                            <Form.Item label="Zip code" name="ZipCode" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                                <Input  />
                                            </Form.Item>
    
                                            <Form.Item label="Country" name="Country" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                                <Input  />
                                            </Form.Item>
    
                                            <Form.Item  label="Phone" name="Phone" rules={[{ required: true }, { max: 10, message: "Enter up to 10 numbers" }]}>
                                                <Input  />
                                            </Form.Item>
    
                                            <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 6 }}>
                                                <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary">
                                                    Submit
                                                </Button>
                                            </Form.Item>
                                </Form>
                      </div>   
                    
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
    
    export default ShippingDetails

backend code:

    const express= require("express");
    const Router=express.Router();
    const crypto=require("crypto");
    const Razorpay = require("razorpay");
    // require("cr")
    // what are all missing 
    //  need to create razor object or instance  and add crypto package is useful to make random string for reciept no. in options property
    
    Router.post('/create-order', async (req, res) => {
       
    
        const {orderAmount}= req.body;
        console.log(orderAmount);
        console.log('this is order amount taken rom frontend data');
      const options = {
          // get the amount dynamically from req.body and multiply by 100 razor pay accepts paise format
          amount: orderAmount * 100, // amount in paise (e.g., 1000 paise = ₹10)
          currency: 'INR',
          // receipt: 'order_receipt',
          receipt:crypto.randomBytes(10).toString("hex"),
          payment_capture: 1,
         };
    
        try {
    // first create razor pay object or instance
            const razorPay = new Razorpay(
                {
                  key_id:process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_KEY_ID,
                  key_secret:process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_SECRET_KEY 
                  // please check the above is available or not
          // console.log(key_id);
                } 
            )
    // the create function take s (options,(error,response)=>{if(error)conslow.log(error); reutrn status as 500})
          // const order =
           await razorPay.orders.create(options,(error,order)=>{
           console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_KEY_ID) ;
           console.log('this is key value'); 
           console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_SECRET_KEY) ;
      console.log('this s secret key');
            if(error)
                  {
                    return res.status(500).json({message:'there is an error while getting order from api'});
                 }
    
                return res.status(200).json({message:"receive order from backend",order:order});
           });
          // send order in response as 200 with order payload
          // res.json(order);
        }
         catch (error) {
          // actually this is executing don't know why it is like that..
          res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to create order' });
        }
      });
    
    
      Router.post("/verify",async(req,res)=>{
        // once payemtn is successful it will send all these values
    // i think once the the checkout popup comes once enter details then we send it's response to this route and extracting the details.
    
                try {
                  
                   const {razorpay_order_id,razorpay_payment_id,razorpay_signature}= req.body;
    console.log(razorpay_order_id,razorpay_payment_id);
                   const sign=razorpay_order_id +"|" +razorpay_payment_id;
    
                    const exprectedSign= crypto.createHmac("sha256",process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_SECRET_KEY)
                    .update(sign.toString())
                    .digest("hex");
    
                    if(razorpay_signature===exprectedSign){
                      // then its a valid signature
                      return res.status(200).json({message:"paymemt verified successfully"});
                    }else{
                        return res.status(400).json({message:"invalid signature send!"});
                    }
    
                } catch (error) {
    
                    console.log(error);
                    res.status(500).json( { message: 'internal server error'} )
                }
           }
      )
    
      module.exports=Router;
```

Comment: @kabileesh please check this code that i have given  i get the error after the clicking pay now button in razorpay

Comment: You need to add the `callback_url` in your options. `handler` function is to handle the success response from the `callback_url`. Kindly check my answer I have included the `callback_url` : `"http://localhost:4000/verify"` (above handler)- this you have given in `handler`. But `handler` itself gets the response from the `callback_url`. So include `callback_url` and test it. It will work, if not ping here.

Comment: @KabileeshG i have added and posted the updated source code in that, error is persist

Answer (score 0):

front-end code:

```
import React from 'react'
import "./shippingDetails.css"
import { Button, Divider, Form, Input, message } from 'antd'
import { useDispatch,useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { updateUserAddress } from '../../Features/signUpSignInFeature/SignUpSignIn'
import "../../projectStyling/RegisterPage.css"
// import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'


function ShippingDetails() {
 const dispatch= useDispatch();
// const navigate=useNavigate();

const currentUserInfo = useSelector((state)=> state.signInSignUp.user);

const initialValues = {
    Name: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.Name : "",
    Street: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.Street : "",
    City: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.City : "",
    State: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.State : "",
    ZipCode: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.ZipCode : "",
    Country: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.Country : "",
    Phone: currentUserInfo.userAddress ? currentUserInfo.userAddress.Phone : "",
  };
  
console.log(currentUserInfo);
console.log(currentUserInfo.userAddress);
console.log('this is current user info and address from redux');
// this currentUserInfo has userId,name,email,wishList,shoppingCartList,userAddress,isUserActive..



const handlePaymentSuccess = async (response) => {
    try {
        console.log('Payment successful:', response);
        // Perform actions on successful payment, e.g., update order status, show success message, etc.
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error handling successful payment:', error);
    }
};

const handlePaymentFailure = async (response) => {
   
     console.log(response);
                    console.log('this is response object in payment failed instance'); 
                    console.log(response.error.description);
                    console.log('this the response.error.description in on event');
    try {
        console.log('Payment failed:', response);
        // Perform actions on failed payment, e.g., show error message, handle retries, etc.
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error handling failed payment:', error);
    }
};


const loadScript = (src) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = src;
      script.onload = () => {
        resolve(true);
      };
      script.onerror = () => {
        resolve(false);
      };
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
  };

const initPayment =async(userInfo,order)=>{

    console.log('i am in intipayment function');

    try {
        
        const res = await loadScript("https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js");
    
        console.log(res);
        console.log('this is res from the razorpay server that im callling expecitly');
            if (!res) {
               alert("Razropay failed to load!!");
               return;
            }

        const options = {
                    key: process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_KEY_ID,
                    amount: order.amount,
                    currency: order.currency,
                    name: userInfo.name,
                    description: 'note : this is just a  Test Payment do not panic',
                    order_id: order.id,
                    callback_url: "http://localhost:4000/verify",
 
                    handler: handlePaymentSuccess, 
                    // mention the callback-url to which the response from the razorpay server will be sent,
                   
                    // handler: async(response)=>{

                    //     try {
                    //         console.log('i am here in handler function..');
                    //         console.log(response);
                    //         console.log('this is the response after the order is created');
                    //         const verifyUrl="http://localhost:4000/verify";
                    //           const {data}=await axios.post(verifyUrl,response);
                    //           console.data(data);
                    //           console.log('i am in handler funtction after verify payment');
                    //     } 
                    //     catch (error) {
                    //       console.log(error);
                    //         console.log('i am in initPayment handler of error...');
                    //     }
                    // },
                    prefill: {
                        // i think we need to use name,email,contact of user not me.
                    // name: 'John Doe',
                    name: userInfo.name,
                    email:userInfo.email,
                    // email: 'john.doe@example.com',
                    contact: userInfo.phone,
                    },
                    theme: {
                    color: '#F37254',
                    },
                    // modal: {
                    // // ondismiss: handlePaymentCancel,
                    // },
            };
            // const razorpayInstance = new window.Razorpay(options);
            const razorpayInstance =new window.Razorpay(options);
// below the error comes
                console.log(razorpayInstance);
                console.log('this is razorpay instance value');
                // this says open () is called with object that's not a razorinstance
                // let's ask in  stackoverflow
                
                razorpayInstance.on("payment.failed", async (response) => {
                    // console.log(response);
                    // console.log('this is response object in payment failed instance'); 
                    // console.log(response.error.description);
                    // console.log('this the response.error.description in on event');
                    handlePaymentFailure(response)
             });


             razorpayInstance.on("payment.successful", async (response) => {
                  console.log(response);
                  console.log('this is the response in payemnt.success on event..');
             })
            razorpayInstance.open();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('failed to create order this is an error');
    }
}

const handlePayment=async(currentUserInfo)=>{
// this currentUserInfo contains userId,name,email,shoppingCartList is array so use [0].actualTotal

     try {

        console.log(currentUserInfo.shoppingCartList[0].actualTotal);
        console.log('this is the actual total that i am going to send in create-order route');
        // if you want or needed you can also add orderAmount, username,userEmail etc and can pass it also...
         const response= await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/create-order",{orderAmount:currentUserInfo.shoppingCartList[0].actualTotal}) //here please pass the actual price.
        //   i think the response now will return the order value
        console.log(response.data);
        // now this returns  and contains order have properties like amount,currency, id,receipt,status,notes as array like that
        console.log('this is the create-order response data in handlePayment function...');

        await initPayment({name:currentUserInfo.name,email:currentUserInfo.email,phone:currentUserInfo.userAddress.Phone},response.data.order);

     } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        message.error( 'there was an error in handlePayment function');
     }
}

const onFinishFunction = async (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    console.log("value inside the shipping details");
    console.log(currentUserInfo);
    console.log('this is user information taken from redux');


    if (currentUserInfo.email !== undefined && currentUserInfo.email !== "") {
         
        try {
                const reduxResult = dispatch(updateUserAddress(value));
                console.log(reduxResult.payload);
                console.log('this is redux result in shipping details');

                const response=axios.post('http://localhost:4000/storeshippingaddress',{userId:currentUserInfo.userId,userAddress:reduxResult.payload})
                console.log(response);
                console.log('this is response from backend when storeshippingaddress api called');
                // navigate('/paymentDetails');


                // let's call the payment method of razorpay
// this currentUserInfo contains userId,name,email,shoppingCartList is array so use [0].actualTotal
                   handlePayment(currentUserInfo);// this is the function that will the payment route for order here i need pass user's information user's name,actual amount,email,,phone number
            } 
            catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                message.error( <span className='custom-message'>{'error while getting user address'}</span> )
            }
               
    } else {
        message.error(<span className='custom-message'>{'Please sign in  to proceed further'}</span>);
        console.log('Email is empty or undefined. Navigation prevented.');
    }


};

    const onFinishFailedFunction =(error)=>{
           console.log(error);
            console.log( "error in shipping details");
            message.error(<span className='custom-message'>{'Please fill all the fields'}</span>);

    }

    return (
        <>
        <Divider></Divider>
            <div className='ShippingDetails'>
               
                  <div className='ShippingHeading'>
                     <h3 style={{color:"black"}}><b>SHIPPING ADDRESS</b></h3>
                  </div>

                  <div className='ShippingBody'>
              
                <Form
                                    initialValues={initialValues}
                                    onFinishFailed={onFinishFailedFunction}
                                    onFinish={onFinishFunction}
                                    labelCol={{ span: 2 }}
                                    wrapperCol={{ offset: 0 }}
                                >
                                    <Form.Item label="Name" name="Name" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                            <Input />
                                            {console.log(currentUserInfo.userAddress.Name)}
                                        </Form.Item>

                                        <Form.Item label="Street" name="Street" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                            <Input />
                                            {console.log(currentUserInfo.userAddress.Street)}
                                            {/* the above is working */}
                                        </Form.Item>

                                        <Form.Item label="City" name="City" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                            <Input />
                                            { console.log(currentUserInfo.userAddress.City) }
                                            {/* the above is working */}
                                        </Form.Item>

                                        <Form.Item  label="State" name="State" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                            <Input  />
                                        </Form.Item>

                                        <Form.Item label="Zip code" name="ZipCode" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                            <Input  />
                                        </Form.Item>

                                        <Form.Item label="Country" name="Country" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                                            <Input  />
                                        </Form.Item>

                                        <Form.Item  label="Phone" name="Phone" rules={[{ required: true }, { max: 10, message: "Enter up to 10 numbers" }]}>
                                            <Input  />
                                        </Form.Item>

                                        <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 6 }}>
                                            <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary">
                                                Submit
                                            </Button>
                                        </Form.Item>
                            </Form>
                  </div>   
                
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default ShippingDetails
```

backend code:

```
const express= require("express");
const Router=express.Router();
const crypto=require("crypto");
const Razorpay = require("razorpay");
// require("cr")
// what are all missing 
//  need to create razor object or instance  and add crypto package is useful to make random string for reciept no. in options property

Router.post('/create-order', async (req, res) => {
   

    const {orderAmount}= req.body;
    console.log(orderAmount);
    console.log('this is order amount taken rom frontend data');
  const options = {
      // get the amount dynamically from req.body and multiply by 100 razor pay accepts paise format
      amount: orderAmount * 100, // amount in paise (e.g., 1000 paise = ₹10)
      currency: 'INR',
      // receipt: 'order_receipt',
      receipt:crypto.randomBytes(10).toString("hex"),
      payment_capture: 1,
     };

    try {
// first create razor pay object or instance
        const razorPay = new Razorpay(
            {
              key_id:process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_KEY_ID,
              key_secret:process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_SECRET_KEY 
              // please check the above is available or not
      // console.log(key_id);
            } 
        )
// the create function take s (options,(error,response)=>{if(error)conslow.log(error); reutrn status as 500})
      // const order =
       await razorPay.orders.create(options,(error,order)=>{
       console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_KEY_ID) ;
       console.log('this is key value'); 
       console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_SECRET_KEY) ;
  console.log('this s secret key');
        if(error)
              {
                return res.status(500).json({message:'there is an error while getting order from api'});
             }

            return res.status(200).json({message:"receive order from backend",order:order});
       });
      // send order in response as 200 with order payload
      // res.json(order);
    }
     catch (error) {
      // actually this is executing don't know why it is like that..
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to create order' });
    }
  });


  Router.post("/verify",async(req,res)=>{
    // once payemtn is successful it will send all these values
// i think once the the checkout popup comes once enter details then we send it's response to this route and extracting the details.

            try {
              
               const {razorpay_order_id,razorpay_payment_id,razorpay_signature}= req.body;
console.log(razorpay_order_id,razorpay_payment_id);
               const sign=razorpay_order_id +"|" +razorpay_payment_id;

                const exprectedSign= crypto.createHmac("sha256",process.env.REACT_APP_RAZOR_PAY_SECRET_KEY)
                .update(sign.toString())
                .digest("hex");

                if(razorpay_signature===exprectedSign){
                  // then its a valid signature
                  return res.status(200).json({message:"paymemt verified successfully"});
                }else{
                    return res.status(400).json({message:"invalid signature send!"});
                }

            } catch (error) {

                console.log(error);
                res.status(500).json( { message: 'internal server error'} )
            }
       }
  )

  module.exports=Router;
```

Comment: @kabileesh  as per your suggestion i have included the callback_url and also the api endpoint but same i am facing the same error I don't know why the error persist i'm unable to make any test payment  as all different service gives error could you check my latest code.?

Comment: Check the `status` from the `network` and the `console` to find out from where the payment gets failed (in which function).  And share the statements that you have got in your `console`.

Comment: i get all error in all payments method the below i got from console:
error
: 
code
: 
"SERVER_ERROR"
description
: 
"We are facing some trouble completing your request at the moment. Please try again shortly."
metadata
: 
{}
reason
: 
"NA"
source
: 
"NA"
step
: 
"NA"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

and for network status i got one red cross  which was  requested URL       =>https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap 

let me know if you need any information further

Comment: moreover i want to use this test mode razorpay in production also like i want to use gateway payment for my dummy where i am going to deploy so that user may not lose original money  so will razorpay allow this ? let me know

Comment: Yeah, you can use test payment gateway in production. Have you checked whether the `/verify` end-point get hit or not in your backend (check by console.log in the backend and see the server message). If so, check where the error happens.

Comment: @kabileesh actually /verify end point is not getting called i have console.log() in verfiy endpoint in express what to do?

Comment: @kabileesh thanks for your help finally i figured out the problem now the it has been resolve the silly mistake was i only created .env file for backend only not frontend later i debug the code and shows undefined so that was the fault so are you sure have you tried razorpay test mode while deploying into the server if yes, tell me any error you faced

Comment: Yeah, I have deployed a module with razorpay test payment gateway and I faced no error. [Here](https://helpful-pegasus-7dc6cc.netlify.app/) I have attached the deployed module and you can check with it. Happy that you have resolved it  : )